# js does not recognize accented chars onclick

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an input element which has an onkeyUp bind.
The problem I am facing is that when a user enters accented chars i.e: Ä ä Ö ö Ü ü
The JS does not fire the onkeyup event/function. on regular chars this works fine.
Also, if I enter an accented char and a regular char (Ös) the bind recognizes both charecters
and fire the event/function.
Also, copy pasting the accented char works great.
Any ideas?

Comment: Without seeing the code looks like a really interesting question, Show some code to make it more interesting!

Comment: There is a simple explanation of that behavioour here: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html

Comment: The title says “onclick”, the question says “onkeyup”. Which one is it?

Comment: Tnx for answering. Its on keyup

Comment: This is the bind for the input:                                           Obj.bind(
                  'keyup' , function(event) {
                 ///some code  
                  })                                                             This works for all charecters except accented and " '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...
I found that accented charecters get to my JS file as keyCode=0, and therefore I ignored them. added a new rule for: (event.keycode==0),
Tnx again.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a swiss keyboard and you are right : `keyup` event returns the same value for chars `é` and `ö` which are provided from the same key (`ö` is activated by `shift`).

You can use `keypress` event to catch all keyboard events including specials keys : http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

Comment: I hope I wont have to use keypress since it fires multipile events if the user holds the key down